# How to only save the commands in oracle sql without the whole file?

Tags: oracle

For example there's this:

> SQL> create table test
> 2 (
> 3 name varchar(9)
> 4 );
>
> Table created.

I only want to save this:

```
create table test
(
name varchar(9)
);
```

I don't want to save the line numbers or the sentence: "Table created."

Comment: What client are you using?  SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL*Plus, as the very next statement, enter:

```
save myddl.sql
```

... and your CREATE TABLE command will be saved in myddl.sql.  You can choose any file name you like (it doesn't have to be myddl.sql).

Comment: but this line will only save the last command, not all the commands.

Comment: If you have multiple commands to run and you want to save them all, then `edit myddl.sql` (or whatever file), then put all your commands in that script, then run the script in SQL*Plus using `@myddl.sql`.